# Rational Parametrization of a curve

Tags: geometry, curves, parametrization

currently, I'm learning how to parametrize basic curves, but I don't understand the Rational Parameterization of a curve.

For example:

$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b} = 1$

or

$y-y_o = a\cdot (x-x_0)^2$

Can someone help me to understand the process?